# Problems with build.xml when using the Android ADK to communicate with an Arduino Mega ADK

Tags: android, arduino, build.xml, adk, processing-ide

So a few days ago I got my hands on an Arduino Mega ADK board, and the last couple of nights I have been setting up my development environment, getting to grips with the tools etc. The tools and libraries all work fine, for example I can get a program written in the Processing IDE to compile and run on an Asus Eee Pad Transformer TF101 running Android 4.03. But when I get it to try to compile and run one of the pre-written examples, it gives me a compiler error:

Android SDK Tools Revision 20
Installed at C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows
Project Type: Application
Project Target:   Android 2.3.3
API level:        10
Library dependencies:
No Libraries

---

API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
No AIDL files to compile.
No RenderScript files to compile.
Generating resource IDs...
Generating BuildConfig class.

BUILD FAILED
C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:680: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:693: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 7 seconds

And that's all the console seems to output as well, which is rather frustrating! As far as I'm aware all of my SDK versions, tools and plugins are all up to date. I've tried this using a Linux partition I have on my hard drive and it produces the same error message, although it mentions a problem with the package com.Android.future.UsbAccessory. Given what I've seen, it seems that the problem is with the tools, either my directory structure doesn't match up to what the correct setup is, or something else is wrong :S. If anyone has had similar problems, some help would be smashing! (For the record, my setup was done using the instructions on the Arduino website, although I already had the Android SDK tools installed).
Will Scott-Jackson

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your haven't added in the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) to your project and/or you haven't downloaded it into your Android SDK.

The ADK1 demokit app targets API Level 10 (Android 2.3.3); That means you need to use the support libraries in your project and that's why the compiler is complaining about level 10 library dependencies not being available. The support libraries are a separate download in the [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html), so you might not have them in your development environment.

In Android API Level 12 and higher, the USB Accessory protocol was added to the framework API, so there are [two different ways](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html#choosing) to use the accessory protocol. So, you don't *have* to use the support libraries if you are targeting Honeycomb and higher versions, but you'll have to update the demokit app code to make this work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I've double checked my setup and started working on a project I had in mind, it seems to import the libraries appropriately. So far so good, but when I input:

```
ArduinoAdkUsb arduino;

void setup() {
     arduino = new ArduinoAdkUsb(this);
     //Other UI initialisation etc. 
}
```

I get this error:

```
##name## ##version## by ##author##
FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.future.usb.UsbManager
    at cc.arduino.ADKCommunication.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at cc.arduino.ArduinoAdkUsb.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at                                                            
    processing.android.test.sketch_120730a.
    sketch_120730a.setup(sketch_120730a.java:48)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

After the app has been built and installed onto the Android tablet I am using. Any thoughts how I can over come this? From what I can tell, this has no problem finding com.android.future.usb.manager to compile and install the program, but once it tries to run it can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this tutorial from http://stream.tellart.com/controlling-arduino-with-android/

In the examples RGB_Arduino the name, version and author variables are set at the top of the sketch.

Try adding in this section of code at the top of your arduino sketch just underneath the library imports

```
// accessory descriptor. It's how Arduino identifies itself to Android
char applicationName[] = "Mega_ADK"; // the app on your phone
char accessoryName[] = "Mega_ADK"; // your Arduino board
char companyName[] = "Freeware";

// make up anything you want for these
char versionNumber[] = "1.0";
char serialNumber[] = "1";
char url[] = "http://labs.arduino.cc/adk/"; // the URL of your app online


//initialize the accessory:
AndroidAccessory usb(companyName, applicationName,
accessoryName,versionNumber,url,serialNumber);
```