# build.xml gives errors when compiling a Processing sketch which includes ArduinoAdkUsb

Tags: android, arduino, processing, build.xml, adk

Software involved:

```
* Latest Android SDK (as of today - 8/29/2012) with all of the latest APIs, Tools, Extras, etc downloaded.
* Processing 2.0a8 (latest build)
* Arduino ADK libraries for Processing ("ArduinoADK-beta-001" folder)
* My system: 64-bit Windows 7
```

I followed instructions [on](http://labs.arduino.cc/ADK/AccessoryMode)  webpage to setup Processing and Arduino IDEs and everything else.  I have an Arduino Mega ADK board.  I uploaded one of the ADK examples to the board with no problems.  Next step was to upload the matching example to Android via Processing.
I have a Nexus One phone (Android version 2.3.6).

```
Android SDK Tools Revision 20.0.3
Installed at D:\Programs\Android SDK
Project Type: Application
Project Target:   Android 2.3.3
API level:        10
Library dependencies:
No Libraries

------------------
API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
No AIDL files to compile.
No RenderScript files to compile.
Generating resource IDs...
Generating BuildConfig class.

BUILD FAILED
D:\Programs\Android SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:679: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Programs\Android SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:692: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds
```

When I upload my own older sketches or any other sketch, that does not use the ADK, the build is successful and the app gets on the phone.
I have spent a lot of time looking for solutions, but so far, no luck.
I found one post in stackoverflow posted by Will Scott-Jackson ( [Problems with build.xml when using the Android ADK to communicate with an Arduino Mega ADK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11493422/1631910) ), who seems to be getting this exact same problem, but no working solutions.
I am not familiar with the java compile processes, manifests, etc; therefore, I am not competent enough to solve this issue by myself.  Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
So I was able to reproduce the same error without using the ADK library in the sketch.  I modified a surfaceTouchEvent with improper return argument and got the same error, which led me to figure out that the error comes from android tools / compiler.

Processing tells me this "Error from inside the Android tools, check the console."

Comment: are you using external jar ??

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal , what jar file are you referring to?

Comment: I guess you have followed all the instructions on this page [processing android wiki page](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android) ? If so then try processing v2.0a7.

Comment: Are you building via the IDE? If so, which IDE? Have you tried command line? `ant` (see http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) **You really want to see the compiler error.**

Comment: What is the status of this with Processing 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your workspace to new location and then again try to run your projects.